# adding border around the text of UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton

I'm trying to make a border around the **text** **itself** (not sure if it's a shadow or not) of a UIButton

Adding an example of how I want it to look like, Tried a "glow" tutorial (http://benscheirman.com/2011/09/creating-a-glow-effect-for-uilabel-and-uibutton/) with no real success

The button is created from StoryBoard

Something similar enough to the example will suffice
[image]

Comment: that called _glow_ not _border_.

Comment: @Varosion - the image is the needed result (photoshop from my designer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a standard `UIButton` with just text, thus without an image, the following snippet should do what you're trying to achieve. 
Make sure `myButton` references to your button and you've imported `QuartzCore`.

```
[[[myButton titleLabel] layer] setShadowOpacity:0.5f];
[[[myButton titleLabel] layer] setShadowOffset:CGSizeZero];
[[[myButton titleLabel] layer] setShadowColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
```

Comment: Not what I intended - it is too spread out. THLabel stroke is more of what I need

Comment: Take a look at the `CALayer` class reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html
You can play with the `shadowRadius` and `shadowOpacity` to get the effect you're trying to create.

Comment: OK. I see what you mean... since the bounty is non-refundable I'll accept your answer. Enjoy... :)

Comment: Okay, thanks :) Btw, you'll have to manually award the bounty.. It won't be awarded to the poster of the accepted answer automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Well, THLabel seems to do the trick (using Stroke option) although the stroke is not glowing, it's a good solution. Thank me for finding it (and posting it here for future refrence)
https://github.com/MuscleRumble/THLabel

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure is that what you want but try

`yourButton.titleLabel.shadowOffset=CGSizeMake(1, 2);
 yourButton.titleLabel.shadowColor=[UIColor redColor];`

Comment: really not what I need. I need a shadow around the entire charachters

Comment: i think u just need a designer